# Mosaico Pre-header "View in Browser" broke all my tokens in the footer

Tags: extension, email

Running: CiviCRM Drupal 4.7.30  Mosaico Ver 2-Beta3, Firefox 58.0.2 (64-bit), Chrome Version 64.0.3282.140 (Official Build)

I love the Mosaico extension but ran into a technical difficulty with tokens in the footer. The tokens in my footer worked as expected in the email, but when I click on the pre-header option "View in Browser" the tokens return the following error:  *Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
Invalid form parameters.*

If I happened to be logged out of CiviCRM when I test my received email the "View in Browser" link returns an "Access Denied" error.

Is this a permissions issue? How is it corrected

Comment: Does this problem happen if you a) update to the latest "development" version of Mosaico, and b) create a new template?  I believe there was a related bug fixed recently - but it didn't fix existing templates, just new ones.

Comment: YES. Using Version 2.0-beta3 Dec 2017 with CiviCRM 4.7.30. Our IT guy said this, "The unsubscribe/forward/etc. links in the footer are mailing and contact specific -- the ids in your links will be different from mine, so the system can track the specific user who received the mailing. The web-view of the mailing is not contact-specific -- it's a generic link that references the mailing -- and could be shared with other people. Consequently, the unsubscribe/forward links lose the ID values (i.e. "missing parameters") specific to the contact.

Comment: "
 

"I feel like what should happen is if someone clicks those links from the context of the web version, we should return them to the page with a message indicating that action links can only be initiated from the mailing."

Comment: Thanks for clarifying - I misread initially!  I'll post an answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak to the first issue, but the second issue (can't "View in Browser" when logged out), I have a solution.

You're looking for the permission labeled *CiviMail: view public CiviMail content*.  Go to CiviCRM's **Administer menu » Users and Permissions » Permissions (Access Control)**.  Select **[Drupal/WordPress/Backdrop/Joomla] Access Control**, and check the appropriate box for anonymous users to view public CiviMail content.